# Prevent non-admins from using Alfresco's /share/page/type/login (normal users go via SSO)

Tags: alfresco

In Alfresco, I have implemented an SSO servlet filter and an AuthenticationComponent so that login is done via SSO.

Everyone logs in via SSO... ***except*** admin users. So, for unauthenticated users my servlet filter redirects to SSO login all pages ***except*** for `/share/page/type/login` and `/share/page/dologin`.

Problem: Normal users might be able to learn about this path, and start using it instead of SSO, which I don't want.

I could generate a very complicated random Alfresco password for all non-admin users, but it sounds rather low-tech.

Is there a solution to effectively restrict login via `/share/page/type/login` to only Alfresco users who belong to the ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS group?

Comment: why don't you redirect this /share/page/type/login page to your SSO login? Let the administrators login via SSO and while processing callback from SSO check whether the users are administrators or not. if they are then redirect them to /share/page/type/login page. So by this you put an extra security layer as well.

Comment: @KintuBarot: The administrators must be able to login even if the SSO infrastructure is down. This is a requirement.